# Getting a specific Observable value

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

So currently I am trying to retrieve the monthlyFee value from this response body.

Comment: What do you see with `console.log(this.currentPlan);`? And what data do you want to get from it?

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in stackblitz? It looks like the response isn't of the type you expect (an array), and I'm still not sure what data you want to extract from the response.

Comment: `Typescript` which you are using in `Angular` is compiled into `JS`, so when you calling `http.post`, there might be different kind of object, that you declared in your `typescript` class. You have to make `1:1` representation of object (or atleast fields you need) to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

Set the response type in your `getCurrentPlan` function:

```
      .subscribe((currentPlanResponse: CurrentPlan[]) => {
        let currentPlan: CurrentPlan[] = currentPlanResponse;
        console.log('monthlyFee: ', 
          currentPlan[0].planGroupMap.sharePlans.plans[0].monthlyFee);
      });
```

Remember that you are getting an array (or nested arrays) so it depends on what you want to do with the final results but the above show who to get the nested values.

Check this StackBlitz I made based on your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-aesbq2

I commented some parts of your code so to not create the whole service and http request but as you said that wasn't your actual problem.

Comment: As Kurt Hamilton said, you should create a Stackblitz with your code. Perhaps the problem is in your `retrieveCurrentPlan` method. In fact you are sending a POST request which could be all right (thou I would have expected it to be a GET request) but then you have to check what data you are sending to the back end. The problem could be that your planGroupMap is undefined but your back end requires that property.

Comment: Is `this.currentPlan` an object or an array? If it's an array then you should select, for example, the first item: `this.currentPlan[0]`.

Comment: How do you declare currentPlan? Do you have `currentPlan: CurrentPlan[]`? Anyway, you should post more could. Without it, it's hard to say what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inspect, what `json` data you are actually receiving and get the required fields using `.` operator, just like you are doing normally. But, to do that, there are two ways you can do it. First you can create a `class`/`interface` which will represent the `json`. Second there is no need to create `class`/`interface` but it will be kinda hard to mantain it. So now you have two ways to do it depends on use case. First, in subscribe `callback`, you are access to it. Second, you can use `pipe` and `map` operator to map result in your service:

```
this.http.post(...).pipe(map(value => value.property))
```

Then object you are received from `backend` will be mapped into `property`